# Offline capture of HTML sign-in sheet form on Mac OS X or iPad

Tags: php, html, forms, offline

I host open house events and want to be able to capture electronic sign-in sheets, but will often not have access to the internet. I want to capture very basic information like first name, last name, email address, phone number and a checkbox that adds an additional space to enter a name if Yes. I want to do this on either my MacBook Air or an iPad. Output should be a simple text file.

I have searched and found that this should work using a basic HTML input form with a PHP script attached.  The HTML file I came up with does display as expected (OpenHouseSignIn.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

input[type=text], select, textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

.container {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Contact Form</h3>

<div class="container">
  <form action="action_page.php" method="post">
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fName" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lName" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

    <label for="phone">Cell Phone</label>
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="cphone" placeholder="Your cell phone..">

    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="emailaddy" placeholder="Your email address..">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

When I click submit on the form from my browser, all I see is the text of the code of action_page.php as shown here:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$fName = "First Name:".$_POST['fName']."
";
$lName = "Last Name:".$_POST['lName']."
";
$phone = "Phone:".$_POST['phone']."
";
$email = "Email:".$_POST['email']."
";
$file=fopen("file.txt", "a");
fwrite($file, $fName);
fwrite($file, $lName);
fwrite($file, $phone);
fwrite($file, $email);

fclose($file);
}
?>
```

I feel like I am very close, but just need an expert to help me!  I have seen some posts mention that I might need to enable PHP on my Mac OS (is that possible on an iPad?), but others that discourage the use of PHP.  Thank you!!

Comment: You need a web server running to be able to submit data to PHP (it's a server side language). Browsers have no clue what PHP is and can't execute PHP code. On your computer, you can make it easy and run [PHP's built-in web server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php). You will also need PHP installed in the computer for this to work. I have no clue how you would do it on the iPad though.

Comment: Thanks, M.  Would you recommend I take a different approach to accomplish this task?  Setting up a web server seems like overkill for capturing data like this?  I can certainly go down the PHP web server route if it is the only way.

Comment: If you use PHP's built-in web server (which I linked to), it's not much of a "set up". You write a single command in CLI.